# Drag and drop without ghost image effect

Tags: javascript

I have the following drag and drop method in my app that sets a ghost image whenever a drag is initiated.

```
function componentDragStarted(e) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = "http://placehold.it/150/29303A/ffffff?text=COMPONENT";
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);

  dragOverQueueProcessTimer = setInterval(function () {
    dragDropFunctions.processDragOverQueue();
  }, 100);

  htmlToInsert = e.originalEvent.srcElement.dataset.insertHtml;
}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the drag item icon to look more like the below (no ghost effect, same shape and type)?

[image]